# Multiple Accept Jquery UI Droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

hi guys i have a 2 draggable divs #schedule and #events and a droppable div #droppable. What i want to do is when i drop #schedule to #droppable it will redirect to some page like schedule.php and the same with #events also. Can anyone show me a sample code for that?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Droppable has an event called 'drop' which is triggered when an accepted draggable is dropped on the droppable. You can specify a handler for this event when you create the droppable.

The signature of the event handler is 'function(event, ui)'. The 'ui' argument will have a property called 'draggable' which in turn will have a property called 'context'. This last property represents the underlying HTML element from which you can retrieve the element id.

You can then use this value to switch to the corresponding page (for instance with window.location.href).

The following sample code shows the (basic) creation of the droppable with the event handler:

```
$('#droppable').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
       var id = ui.draggable.context.id;
       window.location.href = id + '.php';
    }
});
```